# Dynamic background color formatting in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, report

I am currently working on a report in which the columns are dynamic. Now my boss wants to have a pattern on table header like below.

[image: color pattern]

But my columns are dynamic. I have tried using =RowNumber(nothing) mod 7 = n , but i never got the right combination. Please help. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do is unclear ? Can you explain a little more ? do you want dynamic color for the row or the column ?

Comment: I want to have that color arrangement in the column header of the matrix. RowNumber(nothing) does not fit for the job.

Comment: So you want to set the columns header background color alternate after 7 number of columns correct ?

Comment: Can you determine how many columns you are going to create dynamically in sql

Comment: the user has a freedom to pick a number of reporting periods based on his/her selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the column color depending on its count and you are doing the column grouping then

```
 = IIF (CountDistinct(Fields!FieldUsedAsColumnGrouping.Value,"DatasetName") Mod 7 = 0,"grey color","some other color")
```

Hope this helps..In case of issue comment.

Comment: Thanks Coder of Code ! I have tried it. But it didn't work :( Is there a need to have a custom code for this?

Comment: No Need for the custom code for this `CountDistinct` is the default function provided by tool